# Subset selection to identify independent variables that impact the market?

Tags: data, finance, market-data, machine-learning, quants

Given a lot of market-related features (~100 independent variables such as emerging market, developed market, s&p 500, tech sector returns, etc), I need to select a subset of them that are ideally independent and are the major drivers of the global stock market return during time t=t1 to t=t2.

Specifically, the model has to identify important/non-important variables when:
1) the number of independent variables (p) is large (~100)
2) the number of sample size (n) < the number of independent variables (p) and when n >= p

Are Lasso and PCA good ways to accomplish this? I guess Lasso is a simple, easy method. I think that the problem with PCA is that the interpretation of the result is not going to be easy...

Are there academic literature that deals with this problem (selecting a subset of large independent variables to predict the global stock market return)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literature on Lasso for asset pricing is quite recent and there are few references out there yet. The main ones are:

1. [Freyberger, Neuhierl, Weber - Dissecting Characteristics Nonparametrically](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/michael.weber/research/pdf/nonparametrics.pdf) - this uses Lasso.
2. [Huang and Shi (2016)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/Delivery.cfm?abstractid=1573186) - also lasso.
3. [Horowitz (2016)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/caje.12130)  - gives a overview of model selection in high dimensional models

Also several papers on PCA:

4. [Giglio and Xiu (2016)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2865922)
5. [Kelly, Pruitt, and Su (2017)](http://www.utahwfc.org/uploads/2018_Paper_02.pdf)

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. These papers are definitely helpful.. but I was just wondering if there are papers that specifically deal with predicting the global equity market returns.